# What is meant by iTunes Barcode?

Tags: itunes, music

Is it a kind of UPC Barcode or something else and what are it's uses?

Comment: Can you provide some more context? Where have you seen "iTunes barcode" being mentioned? It probably means barcodes in iTunes gift cards...

Comment: If you mean the code to activate the itunes cards you might want to look here: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202644

Answer (score 1):

Barcodes for iTunes are general use UPC barcodes not different from other products.
iTunes requires that all albums have a UPC and all individual songs have an ISRC. ISRC codes are a simple, internationally recognized numbering system for audio and music video recordings. The ISRC, in addition to tracking for Billboard charting, also allows you to get paid for digital music sales by ensuring that your royalties are tracked properly (particularly important for iTunes).
Source - http://simplybarcodes.net/barcode-itune.html